# Ghostscript errors when running in multiple instances

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have an application that converts multiple Postscript Files simultaneously to PDF. 
To do this I call `ps2pdf input.ps output.pdf`.
Sometimes when I have many (let's say >4) files that need to be converted, i get only one pdf and the other conversions fail.
The Problem is, that the failed convertsions will not result to an exitcode of ps2pdf other than 0.
My Version of Ghostscript is 9.16 for Windows x64.

I could not find any bugs in bugzilla that would explain that behavior.

Is there a better solution than checking if output.pdf exists and retry if it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we don't normally expect people to run multiple instances of Ghostscript. However.....

Most likely you have some kind of collision with temporary files, you can probably get around the problem by specifying a temporary file location (a different one for each instance obviously).

Given that the standard version of Ghostscript uses a single DLL its possible also (though much less likely IMO, because the context should not be shared) that you have a problem caused by sharing the DLL. You could set up several directories and use each one individually to see if that helps.

Using a script is probably also not the smartest idea in the world for a complex setup. Invoke Ghostscript directly instead, you will get much more control.

And what messages do you get returned when your conversions fail ? What version of Ghostscript are you using ? On what Operating System ?

Comment: My Version of Ghostscript is 9.16 and it's a Windows 2012 R2 Server x64. The return code was 0 and i didn't see any console output that would explain the behavior. I will try your idea about invoking ghostscript directly and see if it helps. Anyway: the interesting fact is, that the previous version we had (i don't remember the exact version, but it was something with 8.?), did not make problems like that.

Comment: It probably didn't create as many temporary files...... If this is the problem then running GS directly won't make any difference, but it will make it much easier for you to set command line parameters, including giving each instance its own temporary directory. I'd suggest you do that anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`ps2pdf.exe` internally calls `gs.exe` or `mgs.exe` which is `ghostscript`.  You do not need `ps2pdf.exe` you can obtain the same functionality using `gs.exe`.  `ps2pdf.exe` does NOT work properly with several instances.  In fact, `ps2pdf.exe` will execute only once instance at a time.

Answer (score 0):

we found workaround:

```
            var attempts = 0;
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    attempts++;
                    Ghost.Pdf2Image.Convert(pdf_filename);

                    break; 
                }
                catch
                {
                    //prevent forever loops
                    if (attempts > 99) break;
                }
            }
```

This leads to delayed response of hundre ms depending on number of simultanous call. You can work around the delayed response by doing this as async task :)